# SIFT required neighbourhood

Tags: opencv, sift, feature-extraction

I want to use OpenCV's [`SIFT::operator ()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=sift#sift-operator) with `useProvidedKeypoints = true` to describe some features in a *crop* of a larger image (in my application the crop needs to be locally preprocessed and it is not practical / possible to do it for the whole input image - therefore I extract and preprocess a small window around each keypoint and want to get the descriptor).

How many pixels of the *input image* (`img`) are required, how big window do I need to describe the feature? On the first octave, this is `16x16` pixels of the gaussian-filtered image (so technically more than 16 pixels of the original are needed) for a 128-value SIFT. But how does this grow if I require a feature from a different octave? There are some other gaussian filters, which should change the neighbourhood size significantly.

Assume default OpenCV SIFT parameters.